# ACF plugin, displaying as list instead of comma separated

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

A plugin for wordpress called Advanced Custom Fields uses a

```
<?php the_field('field_name'); ?
```

function to display information that I have determined inside WP admin in posts.

However, it outputs it as a comma separated horizontal list (e.g. cow, milk, farm).

I want to output it like this, in an unordered list:

- cow
- milk
- farm

How would I go by doing this?

Comment: Edit the function with the necessary php+HTML

Comment: How do I figure out in which file the function resides?

Answer (score 0):

add css class to your php call, when you creating list, make list and ul, then as cotent call fields..
For more please share your htm/php file, and css also...

Answer (score 0):

In your php file, save the field in an array, and use foreach to create an li foreach string.

What kind of 'Field type' do u use ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $arr = get_the_field('field_name');
    $str = explode (",", $arr);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($str as $s){
        echo '<li>'.$s.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

OR use this code

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/